# escontrar elemento en json con ajax, javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

tengo la siguiente parte de un arreglo de mas valores

```
{
  "name": "karl",
  "age": 50,
  "Numbers": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "fullname": "john W"
    },
    {
      "fullname": "chris b"
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

necesito obtener o mostrar los numbers y references cuando existan, no exiten en todos, algunos tienen tanto el number como las references, ya que son varios.
Gracias.

Comment: solo quieres mostrar los objetos de tu lista si es que tienen numbers o references?

Comment: si, el resultado, por ejemplo si tine number que se muestre (44) 193-6582, y respectivamente en references si las tiene poder mostar el nombre.     <td>${datos.age}</td> asi lo muestro en otros valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar la función [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) que iterará tu lista de datos y de acuerdo a si el elemento evaluado tiene algún valor en su propiedad Numbers o references en sus indice 0 entonces será filtrado a tu nueva variable.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "karl",
    "age": 50,
    "Numbers": [],
    "references": [
      {
        "fullname": "john W"
      },
      {
        "fullname": "chris b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "peter",
    "age": 50,
    "Numbers": [],
    "references": []
  },
  {
    "name": "mike",
    "age": 50,
    "Numbers": [1, 2],
    "references": []
  }
]

const dataFilter = data.filter(i => i.Numbers[0] || i.references[0])

console.log(data)
console.log(dataFilter)
```

Comment: gracias, me sirvió gracias, solo crear otro valor x j para buscar en todas las posiciones del aray